# Support Vector Method

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, svm

I have the following dataset as a small part of the big dataset.
PM2.5 is the dependent variable, while the other seven-column
represent the independent variables, AOD, BLH, RH, WS, Prec. and Temp.

I am looking to use the Support Vector Method SVM multiple regression
to find the best fit multiple variable regression equation using the python code.

I will appreciate your help a lot.

```
PM2.5           AOD     BLH     RH      WS     Prec      Temp   SLP
43.52           0.42    0.39    0.74    1.2    0.4       4.95   1.03
18.4            0.31    0.41    0.71    2.9    0.0       13.4   1.02
53.36           0.30    0.91    0.75    3.21   2.8       17.2   1.01
18.83           0.36    0.29    0.48    1.7    0.6       20.5   1.02
21.2            0.39    0.36    0.52    0.93   0.1       22.0   1.02       
12.17           0.15    0.69    0.52    0.55   0.1       18.67  1.01
8.75            0.11    0.42    0.59    4.98   0.1       18.67  1.01
7.7             0.31    0.048   0.52    0.95   0.0       22.44  1.02
6.58            0.05    0.48    0.57    2.75   0.0       32.38  1.02
```

Data as an `xls` file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CqisyPpSNUMSaRBQjJftMpT_5BgVef64/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Actually I have faced a conceptual problem.
As far as I know, SVM is used to retrieve multiple outputs from single input.
In my case, I was asked to use the opposite; which is retrieving the output (PM2.5) from multiple inputs (AOD, BLH, RH, WS, Prec, Temp and SLP).

Comment: Have you checked out this: https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machine-introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-934a444fca47 ?  They pretty much write the code for you.  You just have to adapt it to your data set.

Comment: @DavidCollins Thank you so much for this nice recommendation, it caused a good development.
I adapted the code according to four parameters of my data set (AOD, BLH, RH, WS).
However, the code takes long time to work and till now there is no any printed results. Only waiting to train the model. 

The code and the used data set as (.csv) file are found on this google drive link:

 

The result is only plotting the first two columns of the data set which is found as "Iris.csv" file on this link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14LvjLvO9EnLBqj6UJfIyCBQvu6bj_1Kv?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14LvjLvO9EnLBqj6UJfIyCBQvu6bj_1Kv?usp=sharing